# Temperature Scale Converter in Clojure

Tags: clojure, unit-conversion

Problem statement:

Write a program that converts all given temperatures from a given input temperature scale to a given output temperature scale. The temperature scales to be supported are Kelvin, Celsius, Fahrenheit, Rankine, Delisle, Newton, Rømer, Réaumur.

Synopsis: `tempconv INPUT_SCALE OUTPUT_SCALE [TEMPERATURE]...`

The `INPUT_SCALE` and `OUTPUT_SCALE` shall be given as follows:

- `K` for Kelvin
- `C` for Celsius
- `F` for Fahrenheit
- `R` for Rankine
- `D` for Delisle
- `N` for Newton
- `Rø` for Rømer
- `Ré` for Réaumur.

Example:

```
tempconv K C 0 273.15 373.15
-273.15
0.0
100.0
```

My solution in Clojure:

```clj
#!/usr/bin/env -S clojure

(defrecord TemperatureConverter [toKelvin fromKelvin names])
(def converters [
  (TemperatureConverter. (fn [kelvin]     kelvin)                                  (fn [kelvin] kelvin)                                  #{"K" "k"})
  (TemperatureConverter. (fn [celsius]    (+ celsius 273.15))                      (fn [kelvin] (- kelvin 273.15))                       #{"°C" "C" "c"})
  (TemperatureConverter. (fn [delisle]    (- 373.15 (* delisle (/ 2 3))))          (fn [kelvin] (/ (* (- 373.15 kelvin) 3) / 2))         #{"°De" "De" "DE" "de"})
  (TemperatureConverter. (fn [fahrenheit] (+ fahrenheit (* 459.67 (/ 5 9))))       (fn [kelvin] (- (* kelvin (/ 9 5)) 459.67))           #{"°F" "F" "f"})
  (TemperatureConverter. (fn [newton]     (+ (* newton * (/ 100  33)) 273.15))     (fn [kelvin] (/ (* (- kelvin 273.15) 33) 100))        #{"°N" "N" "n"})
  (TemperatureConverter. (fn [rankine]    (* rankine (/ 5 9)))                     (fn [kelvin] (/ (* kelvin 9) 5))                      #{"°R" "R" "r"})
  (TemperatureConverter. (fn [réaumur]    (+ (* réaumur (/ 5 4)) 273.15))          (fn [kelvin] (/ (* (- kelvin 273.15) 4) 5))           #{"°Ré" "°Re" "Ré" "RÉ" "ré" "Re" "RE" "re"})
  (TemperatureConverter. (fn [rømer]      (+ (/ (* (- rømer 7.5) 40 ) 21) 273.15)) (fn [kelvin] (+ (/ (* (- kelvin 273.15) 21) 40) 7.5)) #{"°Rø" "°Ro" "Rø" "RØ" "rø" "Ro" "RO" "ro"})
])

(defn getconv [name] (first (filter #(contains? (.names %) name) converters)))

(if-let [[inputScale outputScale & args] *command-line-args*]
  (do
    (def toKelvin (. (getconv inputScale) toKelvin))
    (def fromKelvin (. (getconv outputScale) fromKelvin))
    (doseq [arg args]
      (println (fromKelvin (toKelvin (read-string arg))))
    )
  )
)
```

I seek to understand if there is anything that can be improved, especially if there is some smart way to use a macro to simplify the code that I missed.

Note:

- For now, error handling (user inputs text instead of a number, or an unknown scale) is not of concern.
- I'm aware that my "brace style" with closing parentheses on separate lines is not the usual Lisp/Clojure style that would collect them at the end of the last line. I prefer this way because it causes less noise in diffs in version control.
- I'm aware that the lines defining the temperature converters are long. I usually don't like long lines, but in this case, a tabular layout makes the source code easier to read.

Comment: Fun effort using some obscure scales.  Too bad review sets aside error handling as _error handling_ is such a critical aspect of robust code design.  I'd especially want detection of negative Kelvin errors,

Answer (score 2):

Math detail:

Conversion via the SI unit of [Kelvin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin) is a good approach.

Sometimes numerical computation artifacts though will result in a unexpected result like -1e-16 Kelvin.

To cope with such, consider instead of Kelvin as the central unit, use centiKelvin, then conversions `(+ celsius 273.15))` --> `(+ celsius 27315.0))` and we avoid problems that stem from `273.15` is not *exactly* representable.  For some of the more obscure scales we may need another factor than `x100`, but I hope OP gets the idea.

Answer (score 1):

- I have to repeat that: your "brace style" is bad.
- Use kebab-case for names of record fields: `toKelvin` `fromKelvin` -> `to-kelvin` `from-kelvin`
- Use [different constructor](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide#record-constructors) for records: `TemperatureConverter.` -> `->TemperatureConverter`
- All `from-kelvin` functions have the same name of the argument, so I would also consider rewriting them with anonymous function literal `#(...)` (and that first one is [`identity`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/identity)):

```
(fn [kelvin] kelvin) -> identity
(fn [kelvin] (- kelvin 273.15)) -> #(- % 273.15)
...
```

- You should access record fields with keywords: `:to-kelvin`, `:from-kelvin`, `:names`...
- Function `getconv`: you can rewrite this with [`->>`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) ("thread-last") macro:

```
(defn getconv [name]
  (->> converters
       (filter #(contains? (:names %) name))
       first))
```

- Because your `if-let` has only one branch, [`when-let`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/when-let) will be better (and with that, you can also remove `do`).
- Also use kebab-case for names of variables: `inputScale outputScale` -> `input-scale output-scale`, `toKelvin fromKelvin` -> `to-kelvin from-kelvin`
- `def` creates global variables and you should use it only on the top-level, use [`let`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/let) instead
- You shouldn't use `read-string` for reading data from an untrusted source. While there is safe equivalent [`clojure.edn/read-string`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.edn/read-string), I think you're actually looking for `parse-double`

Main function with all suggested changes:

```
(when-let [[input-scale output-scale & args] *command-line-args*]
  (let [to-kelvin (:to-kelvin (getconv input-scale))
        from-kelvin (:from-kelvin (getconv output-scale))]
    (doseq [arg args]
      (println (from-kelvin (to-kelvin (parse-double arg)))))))
```

(You can add some more [`->`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E) or [`->>`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) for readability.)